# emacsclient not evaluating color-theme?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, debian, emacsclient

When I boot I launch `emacs --daemon`
and it evaluates my `.emacs` with one exception:

> (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.elisp/zenburn-emacs") ;fix loading issue
>
> (require 'zenburn)
>
> ;;; color theme - zenburn?
>
> (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.elisp/color-theme")
>
> (require 'color-theme)
>
> (eval-after-load "color-theme"
>     '(progn
>        (color-theme-initialize)))

I know that the load-path stuff works because `M-x zenburn` loads the color scheme just fine once I launch emacsclient with `emacsclient -nw`.

Does anybody know what is up with `(eval-after-load [snip - see above])`?

Is this a bug?

System Info:

> GNU Emacs 23.2.1
>
> Installed in debian sid on2.6.32-5-amd64 Version: 23.2+1-7
>
> Filename: pool/main/e/emacs23/emacs23_23.2+1-7_amd64.deb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, here's how I load zenburn in my .emacs:

```
(require 'zenburn)
(zenburn)
```

Loads fine via emacsclient.

Comment: zenburn is a shorter alias of the function color-theme-zenburn. The explicit require of color-theme and setq color-theme-is-global are redundant.

Answer (score 3):

And a tip from the current maintainer of Zenburn for Emacs(yours truly):

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.elisp/color-theme")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.elisp/zenburn-emacs")
(require 'zenburn)
(zenburn)
```

You don't need to require color-theme since zenburn requires it internally. You do need, however, to call the zenburn function after you've required zenburn.

You're actually invoking the (zenburn) function when you type M-x zenburn and this is why the theme is getting applied just then instead of on startup.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really say what isn't working?

`(require 'zenburn)` isn't enough to start the theme.
You need to call `(color-theme-zenburn)` as well (or its alias `(zenburn)`, as you are doing interactively).

Comment: I think Phils is right: Instead of your (eval-after-load ...) line, you could just use (zenburn). I don't think color-theme-initialize actually changes the color theme, it just loads libraries.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment:

I have in my `.emacs` file the following line:

```
(setq default-frame-alist '((font . "Inconsolata-20") (tool-bar-lines . 0) (menu-bar-lines . 0)))
```

If I put for example

```
(color-theme-taylor)
```

after this line it works, if I put it before this line, it doesn't.

I.e.

```
(require 'color-theme)
(color-theme-initialize)    

(setq default-frame-alist '((font . "Inconsolata-20") (tool-bar-lines . 0) (menu-bar-lines . 0)))

(color-theme-taylor)
```

works... perhaps your problem may have a similar cause...

Answer (score 0):

Something like `(progn (require 'color-theme) (color-theme-initialize))` should work.  To see `(eval-after-load "color-theme" '(progn (color-theme-initialize)))` does what it should do, check if `color-theme-initialize` is appended to `after-load-alist` (`describe-variable` `C-h v`).  If not, it could be a bug.